# How to convert contingency table obtained using table command to dataframe

Tags: r, pivot, contingency

I am trying to use table function in r to create a contingency table. But instead of a contingency table, I got values (instead of table), list of two.

My data has 15000 observations and 2 variables. The data looks like this:

```
      **Field.Label**                     |**Form.Name**
      ------------------------------------|---------------
      Applicant Name                      |F1
      ------------------------------------|---------------
      Phone                               |F1
      ------------------------------------|---------------
      Address                             |F1
      ------------------------------------|---------------
      Phone                               |F2
      ------------------------------------|---------------
      Address                             |F2
      ------------------------------------|---------------
      Title                               |F2
      ------------------------------------|---------------
      Phone                               |F3
      ------------------------------------|---------------
      ...                                 |...
```

I used following code:

```
      CTable<-table(mydata$Field.Label, mydata$Form.Name)
      CTable<-as.data.frame(CTable)
      View(CTable)
```

And got result like this with 1,665,495 entries (Field.Label has 8,541 levels, and Form.Name has 195 levels. 8,541 * 195 = 1,665,495):

```
      ** Field.Label**                    |** Form.Name** |**Freq**
      ------------------------------------|---------------|-----------
      Applicant Name                      |F1             |1
      ------------------------------------|---------------|-----------
      Phone                               |F1             |1
      ------------------------------------|---------------|-----------
      Address                             |F1             |1
      ------------------------------------|---------------|-----------
      Title                               |F1             |0
      ------------------------------------|---------------|-----------
      Applicant Name                      |F2             |0
      ------------------------------------|---------------|-----------
      Phone                               |F2             |1
      ------------------------------------|---------------|-----------
      Address                             |F2             |1
      ------------------------------------|---------------|-----------
      Title                               |F2             |1
      ------------------------------------|---------------|-----------
      Applicant Name                      |F3             |0
      ------------------------------------|---------------|-----------
      Phone                               |F3             |1
      ------------------------------------|---------------|-----------
      Address                             |F3             |0
      ------------------------------------|---------------|-----------
      Title                               |F3             |0
      ------------------------------------|---------------|-----------
      ...                                 |...
```

How can I get the result of contingency table like the following?

```
                                      |**F1** |**F2** |**F3** |
  ------------------------------------|-------|-------|-------|
  Applicant Name                      | 1     |0      |0      |
  ------------------------------------|-------|-------|-------|
  Phone                               | 1     |1      |1      |
  ------------------------------------|-------|-------|-------|
  Address                             | 1     |1      |0      |
  ------------------------------------|-------|-------|-------|
  Title                               | 0     |1      |0      |
  ------------------------------------|-------|-------|-------|
```

Thanks!

Comment: Search for "reshape wide" or "dcast" and you'll find what you are looking for.

Comment: If @lmo's comment doesn't provide enough leads for you, I suggest you reformat your examples to be something that we can use. These may look fine, but I'm not about to try to manually type all of these in manually to help you (sorry). I'd suggest reading [reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Just don't use the `as.dataframe` part and the value will remain a rather wide table. as.data.frame.table converts a wide format object (that inherits from `matrix`) to a normalized list version.

Comment: @lmo I have tried that but didn't work for me. Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for pointing me to the reproducible examples. This is helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data.Table Solution:**

```
library("data.table")
mydata <- fread('Field.Label,Form.Name
                 Applicant,F1
                 Phone,F1
                 Address,F1
                 Phone,F2
                 Address,F2
                 Title,F2
                 Phone,F3')

CTable <- dcast(setDT(mydata), Field.Label ~ Form.Name, fun = length)
CTable
#    Field.Label F1 F2 F3
# 1:     Address  1  1  0
# 2:   Applicant  1  0  0
# 3:       Phone  1  1  1
# 4:       Title  0  1  0
class(CTable)
# [1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

**Base R Solution:**

```
CTable <- table(mydata$Field.Label, mydata$Form.Name)
CTable <- data.frame(matrix(CTable, nrow = dim(CTable)[1], dimnames = dimnames(CTable)))
CTable
#           F1 F2 F3
# Address    1  1  0
# Applicant  1  0  0
# Phone      1  1  1
# Title      0  1  0
class(CTable)
# [1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: Base R Solution works beautifully. With this method, I don't need to type out all the variable names. Thanks, @Sathish!

Comment: Yes, I'll make sure to do that from now on. Thanks for the tips on how to do so!